# Este JS, starting the android app

Tags: android, react-native

[Este](https://github.com/este/este) is a library "starter kit" for universal apps (web/android/ios).

I build it, and am ready to "start" the app so I can see it on my phone.

The docs say to use "gulp android". This is what happens when I do that.

> Installed on 1 device.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 17.943 secs
>
> This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon:
>   http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Starting the
>   app (/home/james/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n
>   com.este/.MainActivity)... Starting: Intent {
>   cmp=com.este/.MainActivity } [bg] Exited with code 0
>
> But I look at my phone and I get the 'unable to download js bundle'
>   message.

Then I try using "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start" to start the app, on my connected device. I saw this in the Facebook AwesomeApp, (packages.json) so I tried it, and it worked.

This is working, but since I'm new at this, just wondering what is the right way to "start" the app.

I started an issue on their repo, and was told to run

> adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

before

> gulp android

But, "reverse" is not an option on Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31.

It works with my above command, but it's a hack.

Thanks

Update:

I updated my adb to 1.0.32, and now "reverse" is available. But, after running

> gulp android

I run

> adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

and get this error

> error: cannot bind to socket: Address already in use

Comment: "adb reverse" just tells your connected device to look at the computer's port 8081 instead of the device's port 8081. According to [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html), that is the correct way to run it, though.